# yum update error in RHEL 5.11

Tags: repository, yum, rhel

```
http://10.91.209.2:81/builds/rhel/RHEL6.4-Server-x86_64/Server/repodata/af55926cd66a289d9c7eaf352b2ed91ca0e28f91a505fff2b5c4c7cc2f1885e0-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno -3] Error performing checksum
Trying other mirror.
http://10.91.209.2:81/builds/rhel/RHEL6.4-Server-x86_64/Server/repodata/af55926cd66a289d9c7eaf352b2ed91ca0e28f91a505fff2b5c4c7cc2f1885e0-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno -3] Error performing checksum
Trying other mirror.
Error: failure: repodata/af55926cd66a289d9c7eaf352b2ed91ca0e28f91a505fff2b5c4c7cc2f1885e0-primary.sqlite.bz2 from RHEL_Server: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
```

I am getting this error in RHEL 5.7 version,but this error is not occurring in RHEL 6 .

In RHEL 6.7 :-

```
yum repolist
Loaded plugins: product-id, security, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
repo id repo name status
NetAct-product-16.2.0.677 NetAct product 16.2.0.677 1,051
RHEL_HighAvailability "RHEL HighAvailability" 56
RHEL_LoadBalancer "RHEL LoadBalancer" 4
RHEL_ScalableFileSystem "RHEL ScalableFileSystem" 7
RHEL_Server "RHEL Server" 3,648
RHEL_cpf_Errata "RHEL cpf Errata" 4,255
repolist: 9,021
```

In RHEL 5.11:-

```
yum repolist
RHEL_Server/primary_db | 3.1 MB 00:00 <link> [Errno -3] Error performing checksum
Trying other mirror.
repo id repo name status
NetAct-product-16.2.0.677 NetAct product 16.2.0.677 1051
RHEL_Server "RHEL Server" 0
RHEL_cpf_Errata "RHEL cpf Errata" 0
repolist: 1051
```

Comment: What is the configuration for the `RHEL_Server` repository on your CentOS 5.11 machine? Is it trying to use the RHEL 6 repository by any chance?

Comment: Its Red hat 5.11  and not CentOS..                                                     #cat /etc/yum.repos.d/rhel_server.repo
[RHEL_Server]
name="RHEL Server"
baseurl=http://10.91.209.2:81/builds/rhel/RHEL6.4-Server-x86_64/Server/
enabled=0

Comment: Yeah, sorry, finger slip there. Yes, you have it configured to use a RHEL 6 repository. That isn't going to work by default. If you can install the python-hashlib package it might help (it is in EPEL). Otherwise you can use a repository built for RHEL 5 instead of one built for RHEL 6.

Comment: Ok, so the conclusion is RHEL 6 repository is configured in RHEL 5 node by admin unknowingly or by mistake. So the RHEL version should be updated or repository should be updated for RHEL 5.